# How is the last equation derived in this equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From [*Inequalities A Mathematical Olympiad Approach*](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Inequalities%20A%20Mathematical%20Olympiad%20Approach%20-%20Manfrino,%20Ortega,%20and%20Delgado%20(Birkhauser,%202009).pdf), page 122

> Observe that, $$\sum_{i = 1}^n \sqrt{a_i}-(n-1)\sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_i}\sum \sqrt{a_i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{a_i}{1+a_i} \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}\\ = \sum_{i,j} \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} = \sum_{i>j} \dfrac{(\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})^2(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}}$$

I get that one $1+a_j$ factor in the denominator is from the given summation condition and the we applied $a^2-b^2$ for square root in the numerator to get two factors. But where do other factors come from? Also in the summation in the last step, how did we say $i>j$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question to fix it.

Comment: I upload from a mobile, so the appropriate keyboard settings are not there. I'm sorry for the characters not properly presented. I'd really appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{i,j}$ means $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n$ and therefore
\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}+
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}+
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \dfrac{a_j-a_i}{(1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\left(\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}+\dfrac{a_j-a_i}{(1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n}\dfrac{(a_i-a_j)((1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}-(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}}\\
&=\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq n}\dfrac{(\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})^2(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}}
\end{align}
where at the last step we applied
$$(a_i-a_j)=(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})$$
and
$$((1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}-(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i})=
(\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j}).$$

Comment: @EHN Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank You so much, i get it now

Comment: Thanks!! I'll take it

Comment: I'm having some doubts in the first equation where you broke the summation into 2 parts. The LHS runs n×n times. The RHS runs n×(i+j-2) times. How are we inferring that i+j-2=n to make the summation equal to RHS?

Comment: @EHN On the RHS, for $i=j$ the term in the sum is zero, so on the LHS it suffices to consider the case when $i<j$ and $j>i$

Comment: Got it, thanks!!